# Proper location to install services

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I originally posted this question over on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471158/proper-location-to-install-services) but it didn't get any traction so I'll ask here.

In ubuntu or linux in general is there a "correct" location to install services that you download from the internet and want to run. I would like to have services such as redis or ventrilo auto run but to me it doesn't make sense to put them in the ~/redis or ~/ventrilo directories since they aren't user specific.

Keep in mind that I'm relatively new to the linux world having been a .Net developer for about 4 years now.

Comment: Or RedHat. RedHat still has /etc/init.d for daemons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So according to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) software manually installed should be placed into `/usr/local/`, see `man hier` for more details.

In the *nix world, services are called [daemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) and they're typically controlled by [init scripts](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts).  Software installed using your distro's package manager (apt, yum, pacman) should have init scripts included.  Your system's init scripts can be found in `/etc/init.d/`.  If you're compiling/installing software manually, you may have to write your own init script.  If thats the case, there's a template in `/etc/init.d/skeleton`

Comment: +1 BUT: Most linux distros don't use SysV style init (/etc/init.d) anymore, and even fewer will in the future.  While the init systems they do use (predominantly, `systemd`) are *usually* compatible with scripts placed in `/etc/init.d`, for the most part standard system daemons *are not* "controlled by init scripts" -- they're controlled by `init`, and started via whatever configuration method is used by the particular init system.  I.e., most of them *do not* have scripts in `/etc/init.d` on most distros (notable exceptions being Debian and CentOS, but both of those are moving to systemd).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132 `/etc/init.d/skeleton` is no more.